# Instagram Graph API for fetch profile returns an empty array

Tags: instagram, instagram-graph-api

I am trying to fetch Instagram profile(id,name,email, e.t.c) through Facebook using the Facebook Graph API endpoint *https://graph.facebook.com/v17.0/me/accounts?fields=instagram_business_account* on the Graph Explorer tool but it is returning an empty array.

The Instagram is a business account and has already been connected to the Facebook page.

I am using the permissions below to make the call:
public_profile, pages_show_list, pages_read_engagement, instagram_basic

What more do i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

A few weeks ago graph api had this issue on accounts node [(see here)](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/602264498523167/).
I myself noticed it on my production app.
At that point i started using **v16.0** to bypass the issue, but sounds like they fixed it and I was able to go back to v18.0 again.

Anyway, Double check users token.

Try the Debug Token endpoint (graph.facebook.com/debug_token?access_token=[YourAppAdminToken]&input_token=[UsersToken]) and check the "instagram_basic" permission under pages granular scope.